# Factoring algebraic expressions of three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I want to factor $$bc^2+ab^2+a^2c-b^2c-ac^2-a^2b$$

Using Wolfram, I know it's factored into $$-(a-b)(a-c)(b-c) = (b-a)(a-c)(b-c)$$

However, I don't think I ever got taught how to simplify such expression by hand.

- What's the general methodology for this?
- Is there any *mental-tool* that could be used to do this without the experience to spot factors by sight?

Comment: The power on $a$ appears to be in error.  I believe that you meant $a^2c$.  I tried to edit it, but it's too small an edit for me to perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expression deduced from a pattern by a circular permutation on the variables; it is more apparent if you rewrite it as:
$$ab^2+bc^2+ca^2- a^2b-b^2c-c^2a$$
To (try to) factor it, a strategy consists in breaking the symmetry between variables, e.g. by replacing $b-a$ with $(b-c)+(c-a)$:

\begin{align*}
ab^2+bc^2+ca^2- a^2b-b^2c-c^2a&= ab(b-a)+bc(c-b)+ca(a-c)\\
&=ab(b-c)+ab(c-a)+bc(c-b)+ca(a-c)\\
&=(ab-bc)(b-c)+(ab-ca)(c-a)\\
&=b(a-c)(b-c)+a(b-c)(c-a)\\
&=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a).
\end{align*}